# how can i code this widget on client side without a need for a server

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I want to code the same widget available on w3schol. The widget is used to transform XML using XSLT and display the result in web browser  with two text area and a zone to display the result bellow.I have included the widget in the url below. The problem is that i need it to function on a client side without the intervention of the server.Is that possible ? and how can it be done?
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: May be its not possible because somewhere you want to put your ".xml" file so, where you put them ?

Comment: IMHO, you should tag your question `javascript`.

Comment: from where you get your xml file??is it hard coded or from server side??

Comment: The XML and the XSLT are both entered in the text are as the  example of the w3school than the user clicks on the button to see the results bellow

Comment: Which browsers do you target? Doing client-side XSLT with script is very different in IE compared to other browsers like Firefox or Chrome.